# Colored Bar Graph According to its Value - GNU Octave

Tags: octave, octave-gui

I want to set the color of the bar graph according to its value. Here is the data

| Kp index | UT |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 76.00 |
| 2 | 76.12 |
| 5 | 76.25 |
| 6 | 76.37 |
| 5 | 76.50 |
| 8 | 76.62 |
| 8 | 76.75 |
| 7 | 76.87 |
| 8 | 77.00 |

This is what I wan to replicate:

[image]

```
**0-3 = green;
4 = yellow;
5-9 = red**
```

I tried ***for loop*** but it was not successful.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You can draw your bar graph one bar at a time, so that you can have full control of each bar as a separate graphics object:

```
x = 1:10;
y = randi( 10, [1,10] );
colours = { 'g', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'y', 'r', 'r', 'r', 'r', 'r' };

hold on
for i = 1 : length(x)
  H(i) = bar( x(i), y(i), 0.4, 'facecolor', colours{i} );
endfor
hold off;
```

[image]

---

<sub>PS. Alternatively, if you don't want that much fine-grained control, and you know that a group will always have the same colour, then you can draw each 'group' separately, instead of each bar separately, and simply set a single colour for the whole group.</sub>